# Matlab: Compare (nearly) the same signal with a different sampling rate

Tags: matlab

Here is my matlab problem:
I have two signals (time/distance excitations).They are called sig_one and sig_two. Sig_one is a simulation signal and sig_two is an on-track measurement signal.

I want to compare both signals. Both signals have a different sampling rate. My simulation signal has 600 Hertz and the on-track measurement signal has approx. 100 Hertz.
I want to compare both signals to check if there is a difference. The simulation signal starts at 0 seconds and ends 200 seconds later but the on track measurement signal starts later at 2.1431 seconds and ends by 200.2463 seconds.

Conclusion both signals have a different size (XXX*2 double array). How can I interpolate the measurement signal to compare it with the simulation signal and plot it? Thank you for answer!

sig_one:

```
[s] [mm]
DATA
0.0000000000e+00    -9.2010301749e+00
2.0000000000e-03    -9.2061877312e+00
4.0000000000e-03    -9.2118709835e+00
6.0000000000e-03    -9.2180018117e+00
8.0000000000e-03    -9.2244784046e+00
1.0000000000e-02    -9.2311885833e+00
1.2000000000e-02    -9.2380179051e+00
```

sig_two:

```
2.1428223 0.0060634273 
2.152832 0.018430086 
2.1628418 0.034733064 
2.1728516 0.058855027 
2.1828613 0.070850573 
2.1928711 0.096776709 
2.2028809 0.14273462 
2.2128906 0.17558892
```

This is only the beginning of the two signals.

Comment: You should resample your simulation signal at the points where you measured. Use `interp1`.

Comment: ok i understand how can i use this command?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html